# Retrieving info from multiple sensors using Windows Sensor API

Tags: c++, winapi, com, sensors

I am using the Windows Sensor API to get info from various sensors including accelerometer and gyroscope. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sensorsapi/sensor-api-programming-guide)

My initial implementation of sensor driver for accelerometer worked - I asynchronously can get the values for that sensor.

The working initialization code for a single sensor (accelerometer) looks like the following:

```
void initialize1(AccelerometerCallBack callBack) {

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);

    ISensorManager* pSensorManager = NULL;
    ISensorCollection* pSensorColl = NULL;
    ISensor* accelerometer = NULL;

    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SensorManager,
        NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&pSensorManager));

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        printf("Succeeded getting Sensor...\n");
        ULONG ulCount = 0;
        // Verify that the collection contains
        // at least one sensor.
        hr = pSensorColl->GetCount(&ulCount);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            if (ulCount < 1)
            {
                wprintf_s(L"\nNo sensors of the requested category.\n");
                hr = E_UNEXPECTED;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("Failed to get Sensor...\n");
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Get the first available sensor.
        hr = pSensorColl->GetAt(0, &accelerometer);

        BSTR name = 0;
        hr = accelerometer->GetFriendlyName(&name);
        wprintf(L"%s\n", name);
    }

    AccelerometerEvent* pEventClass = NULL;
    ISensorEvents* pMyEvents = NULL;
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Create an instance of the event class.
        pEventClass = new(std::nothrow) AccelerometerEvent();
        pEventClass->globalCallBack = callBack;
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Retrieve the pointer to the callback interface.
        hr = pEventClass->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pMyEvents));
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Start receiving events.
        hr = accelerometer->SetEventSink(pMyEvents);
    }

    MSG msg;
    BOOL bRet;
    while ((bRet = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) != 0)
    {
        if (bRet == -1)
        {
        // handle the error and possibly exit
        }
        else
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I wanted to simultaneously get the gyroscope, so I add a similar initialization code:

`void initialize2(GyroscopeCallBack callBack);`, which does similar thing as above.

Now my C# layer triggers those code like this:

```
internal void Start()
{
    AccelerometerCallBack myCallBack1 = new AccelerometerCallBack(onAccelerometerDataChanged);
    initialize1(myCallBack1);

    GyroscopeCallBack myCallBack2 = new GyroscopeCallBack(onGyroscopeDataChanged);
    initialize2(myCallBack2);
}
```

However, only the accelerometer info is received through the callback, not the gyroscope's.

- I have confirmed that my device has both sensors of the correct type
- I have confirmed that my callback functions and C# to C++ interface all works properly

**What is the correct way to "fetch" multiple sensors (instead of one) using the Windows Sensor API?**

There are no examples on the official website about doing this, and the only related SO post ([Exposing multiple sensors on a single device to Windows Sensor API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14325827/exposing-multiple-sensors-on-a-single-device-to-windows-sensor-api)) does not help. Thanks!

Comment: If you only load the gyroscope, does it work? Try the sensor diagnostic tool to verify that it is not a hardware limitation. Sensors can be loaded together.

Comment: All you have shown is the code that creates an `ISensorManager` COM object, but not any of the code that actually uses it, or sets up the individual sensors and their event sinks, or processes their events. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem in action.

Comment: What the code "do more here" is? Is there anything like `while(true)` or other loop in it? And can you make sure that the program actually runs to the line `new GyroscopeCallBack()` ?

Comment: @Michael If I only load the gyroscope, it does work.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I would put the complete verifiable example, but I am afraid it might get the post too long, so I just wanted some suggestions.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT I have confirmed that the callback (C# to C++) works fine for both sensors. It just does not work when I initialize both of them together.

Comment: I have a gut feeling that it may because of `CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);` and the message pump `GetMessage()` that is somehow blocking other sensor callbacks, but I have no clue on how to solve the issue.

Comment: @JohnW you should not be calling `CoInitializeEx` inside your sensor initialization functions at all. That belongs in your app startup code instead. But the main problem is that you are simply doing ALL of the work for the accelerometer before you even touch the gyroscope. That's easy to fix, just break up the code a little. Create 1 SensorManager, then setup the event sinks for both sensors within it, then run the message loop. Your initialization functions are doing more than just initialization, the message loop needs to be taken out of them and handled separately.

Comment: @JohnW As I have metioned,  Your initialization functions will not return unless the `GetMessage()` return 0. So the next line will not be executed.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT You are right. Is there a way to keep the sensor events triggering without using a Message pump? So far, that was the only way I could get this sensor events triggering constantly, but I would prefer not to use it since as you said it will not execute the next line unless the return value is 0.

Answer (score 0):

It worked! Solution was to remove the message pump and use `COINIT_MULTITHREADED` option for `Coinitializine()`. Thanks for all the help.